# Compiler error, while creating pdf using pylatex

Tags: python-3.x, pylatex

I am using PyLaTex to create a pdf document. I'm facing some issues with compilers.

I am running my program on MacOS-High Sierra, and have installed basic version of MacTeX [Mactex Download](https://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) and latexmk is also [installed](https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/) using

```
sudo tlmgr install latexmk
```

For the following starter code, I'm getting error in compilers loop. Here's the error log attached after code.

```
import numpy as np

from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Tabular, Math, TikZ, Axis, \
    Plot, Figure, Matrix, Alignat
from pylatex.utils import italic
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
#     image_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'kitten.jpg')

    geometry_options = {"tmargin": "1cm", "lmargin": "10cm"}
    doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)

    with doc.create(Section('The simple stuff')):
        doc.append('Some regular text and some')
        doc.append(italic('italic text. '))
        doc.append('\nAlso some crazy characters: $&#{}')
        with doc.create(Subsection('Math that is incorrect')):
            doc.append(Math(data=['2*3', '=', 9]))

        with doc.create(Subsection('Table of something')):
            with doc.create(Tabular('rc|cl')) as table:
                table.add_hline()
                table.add_row((1, 2, 3, 4))
                table.add_hline(1, 2)
                table.add_empty_row()
                table.add_row((4, 5, 6, 7))


    doc.generate_pdf('full', clean_tex=False, compiler_args='--latexmk')
```

Error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-dbe7f407e095> in <module>()
     27 
     28 
---> 29     doc.generate_pdf('full', clean_tex=False, compiler_args='--latexmk')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylatex/document.py in generate_pdf(self, filepath, clean, clean_tex, compiler, compiler_args, silent)
    227 
    228         for compiler, arguments in compilers:
--> 229             command = [compiler] + arguments + compiler_args + main_arguments
    230 
    231             try:

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Please help me understand the error and fix the same
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a confusion between the `compiler` keyword argument, which accepts a string and `compiler_args` which accepts a list.
Maybe something like this is what you're after:

```
doc.generate_pdf('full', clean_tex=False, compiler='latexmk', compiler_args=['-c'])
```